# Fourier transform probability distribution

Tags: probability-distributions, fourier-analysis

Suppose I have 1,000 independent random values with a uniform distribution $[+1, -1]$. Now suppose I take the discrete Fourier transform of this data. What the heck is the probability distribution of the resulting Fourier coefficients?

(I'm *guessing* it's either uniformly distributed again, or else some manner of exotic distribution which converges to a normal distribution if the number of samples is high enough...)

---

**Edit:**

Each coefficient produced by the Fourier transform is the weighted sum of the input samples.

It appears that if $x$ and $y$ are both random variables, then the probability distribution of $x+y$ is equal to the convolution of the probability distribution for $x$ and the probability distribution for $y$. [Obviously, this applies iff $x$ and $y$ are *independent*.] I think I read that right, anyway!

If we were just summing $N$ I.I.D. variables, the result would be a normal distribution. But because it's a *weighted* sum, each *weighted* variable has a different [uniform] distribution. So... that means the answer is... uh...??

Comment: May I ask discrete Fourier transform of what? So you have a vector $(a_1, ..., a_{1000}) \in [-1,1]^{1000}$ and you take the discrete Fourier transform of this vector? Or you bin the data, and take the discrete Fourier transform of the binned data?

Comment: Just for the sake of curiosity, I tested in matlab what I interpreted to be the question: N=1e5;a=-1+2*rand(N,1);f=real(fftshift(fft(a)));histfit(f,50); and got what very much looks like a normal distribution (same for the the imaginary part) which, I suppose, is what the question is about. Could this somehow be related to the Box-Muller transform?

Comment: It does seem from Box-Muller that you'd be computing a weighted combination of normal components, and so the result ought to be normal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The complex Fourier coefficients of a random series form a 2-D normal distribution in the complex plane (a Gaussian rotated around zero). When taking the magnitude of the complex spectrum, at each magnitude $r$ (the distance from the origin) the probability density will be $2 \pi r dr$, multiplied by the Gaussian, which gives (up to some constants) $r*\exp(-r^2)$. Incidentally, this does not depend on the shape of the original random distribution (from the central limit theorem, I guess). I tried in Matlab randn(...) (normally distributed), rand(...) (uniformly distributed) or rand(...)>.5 (zeros and ones only). Magic!

Comment: Do you have a suggestion how to see your observations not only in a MATLAB simulation but also in mathematical equations? So, do you have an idea how to proof this?